# How to train a siamese neural network for image matching?

Tags: keras

I need to identify if two fingerprints (from id card and sensor) match or not. Below some examples from my database (3000 pairs of images):

1. Example of matching images

[image]

2. Example of non-matching images

[image]

I am trying to train a siamese network which receives a pair of images and its output is [1, 0] if they don't match and [0, 1] if they match, then I created my model with Keras:

```
image_left = Input(shape=(200, 200, 1))
image_right = Input(shape=(200, 200, 1))

vector_left = conv_base(image_left)
vector_right = conv_base(image_right)

merged_features = concatenate([vector_left, vector_right], axis=-1)

fc1 = Dense(64, activation='relu')(merged_features)
fc1 = Dropout(0.2)(fc1)

# # fc2 = Dense(128, activation='relu')(fc1)

pred = Dense(2, activation='softmax')(fc1)

model = Model(inputs=[image_left, image_right], outputs=pred)
```

Where `conv_base` is a convolutional architecture. Actually, I have tried with `ResNet`, `leNet`, `MobileNetV2` and `NASNet` from `keras.applications`, but they don't work.

```
conv_base = NASNetMobile(weights = None,
                        include_top=True,
                       classes=256)
```

My model summary is similar as shown below (depending on corresponding network used):

```
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                    Output Shape         Param #     Connected to                     
==================================================================================================
input_2 (InputLayer)            (None, 200, 200, 1)  0                                            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
input_3 (InputLayer)            (None, 200, 200, 1)  0                                            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
NASNet (Model)                  (None, 256)          4539732     input_2[0][0]                    
                                                                 input_3[0][0]                    
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
concatenate_5 (Concatenate)     (None, 512)          0           NASNet[1][0]                     
                                                                 NASNet[2][0]                     
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dense_1 (Dense)                 (None, 64)           32832       concatenate_5[0][0]              
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dropout_1 (Dropout)             (None, 64)           0           dense_1[0][0]                    
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dense_2 (Dense)                 (None, 2)            130         dropout_1[0][0]                  
==================================================================================================
Total params: 4,572,694
Trainable params: 4,535,956
Non-trainable params: 36,738
```

Additional to convolutional architecture changes, I've tried with using pre-trained weights, setting all layers as trainable, setting last convolutional layers as trainable, data augmentation, using `categorical_crossentropy` and `contrastive_loss` functions, changing learning rate, but they all have same behavior. It is, training and validation accuracy are always 0.5.

Does anybody have an idea about what I am missing/doing wrong?

Thank you.

Comment: You can refer this -> “Face Recognition from Scratch using Siamese Networks and TensorFlow” by Shubham Panchal https://link.medium.com/HT66TqDdCV

Comment: You are not finding the abs distance between the vectors `| vector_left - vector_right |` and then pass it to the last Dense layer.